# How to search items in a DB using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, tapestry

I'm new (very new) to hibernate. I'm using Hibernate with Tapestry. What i want to do is search some element in the DB. I have userId, username and password in the DB ( and a class named User). I need to check the input string with the username, and if its there then need to check the password is right.

```
List<User> moderators =  session.createCriteria(User.class).list();
```

I can get the list of objects and search though it. but i believe Hibernate will do it better and faster. Can any one tell me how to do it?

Comment: Sounds like you have some reading to do. HQL is your friend here.

Comment: read about how to query with HQL or Criteria